Can I use an old laptop as an SSD enclosure for cloning an SSD?
I have two M2 SSDs (one 128Gb, one 256Gb) and also 2 laptops, each with a single M2 slot.  I want to clone the smaller SSD onto the bigger one.  I'm fine using Clonezilla for this.
My question is whether there is any way of doing this with my existing hardware without having to buy an enclosure?  Something like a NAS liveCD but with low-enough-level access to allow actual cloning?
Or to put it another way: can I use one of the laptops like an enclosure for this procedure?
(the laptops are both Ubuntu 20.04, and the SSD I want to clone is bootable with Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04, UEFI).

can I use one of the laptops like an enclosure for this procedure? No, you can't.

Yes, you can.
If you want to create a couple of USB (or DVD) Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS installers, then you could boot each machine to a live version of Ubuntu Server and copy (dd) the smaller drive to the larger drive. I tested using machines connected by ethernet.
Basically, you boot and follow the menus until you reach this display.

From here, navigate to select "Enter shell", as shown below.

You should get a command prompt, as shown below.

When entering the following commands, note the following.

You will be creating a temporary Network Block Device (NBD).
You can ignore the warning message regarding oldstyle protocol.
The port number 10809 was picked at random.
I used the IPv4 address given by hostname -I when the nbd-client command required and IP address.

For the machine with the smaller drive, enter the following.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nbd-server
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/nvme0n1
sudo ndb-server 10809 /dev/nvme0n1
hostname -I

For the machine with the larger drive, enter the following.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nbd-client
sudo ndb-client <server IPv4 address> 10809 /dev/nbd0
sudo dd if=/dev/nbd0 bs=1M status=progress of=/dev/nvme0n1
sudo ndb-client -d /dev/nbd0
sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1

The gdisk command is interactive. Enter the characters given in the first column of the table below.



Entry
Type
Comment




x
Command
Select extra functionality menu


e
Command
Relocate backup data structures to the end of the disk


w
Command
Write table to disk and exit


y
Parameter
Confirm to proceed




Note: I was able to transfer 1 GiB in about 25 seconds. Based on this, a 128 GB drive should take about 50 minutes to transfer.

When finished, you can enter the command below to shutdown each machine.
shutdown now


Worked flawlessly!  256GB took about 20 minutes via my router.  Warning for anyone else trying this: be extremely careful - typing even slightly the wrong parameters for the dd command can easily result in the disappearance of all your data.  You must get the device names right - you can use e.g. lsblk to find the correct ones for your setup.  The names in the answer above may be different.

No, you cannot.
Drive enclosures are simpler, and have chips on them that handle the duties of a drive enclosure and that allow connection via the supported connection options. Laptops are more capable and complex, but that does not mean they are capable of pretending to be something that they are not.
Being more complex and capable does not mean something can become something simpler.
